# Python 3: How do I use bytes-to-bytes and string-to-string encodings

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x

Check out the bytes-to-bytes and string-to-string encodings in Python 3:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings (Search for `bytes-to-bytes`)

How do I use these? I've tried using them in `.encode` and `.decode` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing them through the `codecs` module by a non-alias name seems to work, in Python 3.2 and above:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b"asdf", "base64_codec")
b'j\xc7_'
>>> codecs.encode(b"asdf", "base64_codec")
b'YXNkZg==\n'
>>>
```

Using an alias name (`"base64"`), Python < 3.2, or `bytes.decode` all seem to fail.

Comment: Is this really the shortest way? That kinda sucks.

Comment: @RamRachum Semantically, in Python 3, `encode` and `decode` are use specifically in respect to unicode, which is why `bytes` doesn't have `encode`, and `str` doesn't have `decode`. While it's less convenient than Python 2, it does separate going to and from unicode from other forms of text / byte manipulation.

Comment: @RamRachum: How does this in any universe "kinda suck"? That code is clear, readable, pretty obvious and not particularly long?

Comment: In this very universe where a language called Python 2.x exists. Whether you say this sucks depends on what you compare it to. I'm sure that there are some languages that if you'd compare it to, you'd think it's not particularly long. But if you compare it to Python 2, it's about TWICE as long.